# Alterar posições de um inteiro

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

> Citação

Estou construindo um sql onde tenho a seguinte informação yyyymmdd 20190327 está no banco como inteiro, preciso converter em ddmmyyyy 27032019 continuando sendo um inteiro no select. 
Tem alguma função que faça isso?

Resolvido:

```
CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(10), 20190327)),105),'-',''))
```

Comment: tem sim, `convert` e `cast`

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o `convert`:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), 20190327));
```

Para converter a data pra número pode fazer assim:

```
select CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),112) as int)
```

Ou seja, converte para varchar primeiro e deopis para int. Por que o 112?
Porque na função `convert`, esse é o formato para data yyyymmdd:

[SQL-Server Cast e Convert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Aqui o fiddle funcionando: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/40042)

Comment: Dessa forma converto em date, agora tenho que pegar a data "2019-03-27T00:00:00Z" e converter em um inteiro 27032019

Comment: editei a pergunta com um exemplo para converter a data para número.

Answer (score 0):

Ficando no contexto puramente numérico, eis outra solução:

```
-- código #1
SELECT ((coluna % 100) * 1000000) +           -- dia
       (((coluna / 100) % 100) * 10000) +     -- mês
       (coluna / 10000)                       -- ano
  from ...
  where ...
```